# Адаптивные растянутые инпуты

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет ребят, возникла такая проблема. не могу задать ширину инпуту. Ну не растягивается во всю ширину и все. Кто-нибудь встречался с такой проблемкой?
Как сделать адаптивный инпут?

Comment: У вас родители не имеют ширину 100%

Comment: всем родителям выше нужно указать ширину

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример, если родитель имеет ширину небольшую, инпут будет таким же.

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
}

.form {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```